# Django is trying to use PSQL 9.6, while 12.15 is installed, raising a "raise NotSupportedError"

Tags: django, postgresql

- I verified that I actually have:
  **(PostgreSQL) 12.15 (Ubuntu 12.15-1.pgdg22.04+1)**, when I run the command **psql --version**.
- When I run
  **python3 manage.py dbshell**, I get this result:

  **psql (12.15 (Ubuntu 12.15-1.pgdg22.04+1), server 9.6.24)
  SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)**
- I tried
  **ps aux | grep postgres** and I see a list with only **12/main**, and there is no **9.6.24** anywhere as the Error indicated.

Comment: Uninstall all old PostgreSQL software.

Comment: The thing is though the old (9.6 version) is not installed.

Comment: The server you are connecting to is 9.6.24.  Upgrading the client can't change that.  Look at your connection settings.  If you connecting to a database on some other machine, it doesn't matter what db you have installed locally.

Comment: psql is the client, not the database server. To get the server version, you need pg_ctl: `pg_ctl  --version`. See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html

Comment: Thanks all for your responses.
The issue was that I had a newer version of django, so I installed Django 3.2 and that solved the issue.